# Python ValueCan3 Module/Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a ValueCan 3 Module that I want to use in order to perform some test into my hardware. I need to send some strings to enable a debug mode in side of my module. I have the strings I need to send, but I don't know how. Here is a link of the module I'm referring, http://store.intrepidcs.com/ValueCAN3-DW-2-Channel-p/vcan-dw3.htm Just wondering if anyone has a clue of how to communicate/interact with the module.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After install the ValueCan driver, you can use the library python-ics, which provides the interface to the icsneo40 dynamic library.

Make sure icsneo40.dll in the system.

Use pip to install:

```
pip install python_ics
```

Sample code to initial the ValueCAN and transmit a frame of message:

```
import ics
device = ics.find_devices()[0]
ics.open_device(device)

msg = ics.SpyMessage() # Setup the message
msg.ArbIDOrHeader = 0x411  # CAN ID
msg.NetworkID = ics.NETID_HSCAN # Channel 1 on the ValueCAN
msg.Data = (0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0) # CAN Data field

ics.transmit_messages(device, msg) # Transmit the message
```

- GitHub page for the python library: https://github.com/intrepidcs/python_ics
- Document: http://python-ics.readthedocs.io/